# ¿Cómo se puede incluir el valor de una variable de PHP en el atributo id de una etiqueta HTML?

Tags: php, html5

Tengo una variable php donde tengo guardada una sentencia SQL y dentro del body en html mediante un bucle while que ejecuta el resto de la instrucción con php estoy creando items (contenedores) en donde necesito poner identificadores para poder especificar en javascript el contenedor que se vaya a modificar.

tengo 2 sentencias en el archivo, la 1a solo es de un contador de los items disponibles en la tabla de datos y la 2a me devuelve dos datos de la o las tuplas que cumplan una condición.

la tabla de datos se encuentra en una base de MySQL con phpMyAdmin

en el archivo html tengo:

```
<?php
   $res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(ID_PRODUCTO) FROM producto WHERE DISPONIBILIDAD = 1 AND ID_CATEGORIA = 17");
   $res2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, PRECIO FROM producto WHERE DISPONIBILIDAD = 1 AND ID_CATEGORIA = 17");
<body>
      <?php
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) {
            ?>
               <div class="item">
                  <img class="trj_img_cls" src="RSC/COMING_SOON.jpg" alt="" id="imgDG">
                  <div class="texto_trj">
                     <div class="nombre_producto">
                        <h2 id="ttlDG">título</h2>
                     </div>
                     <div class="precio_producto">
                        <i class="icon-dollar"></i>
                        <label id="precioDG">0.00</label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="caracteristicas">
                        <ul id="caractDG"></ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>

            <?php
         }
      ?>
</body>
```

Utilizo `$res2` ya que se me va imprimir n veces porque tiene varias tuplas a diferencia de `res` que solo tiene un solo dato

solo que no tengo una idea clara de como obtener una variable que contenga como el índice para poder agregar esta variable a los identificadores.

*por decir estoy imaginándome que la variable me sirva para en el identificador del elemento además de lo que ya esta escrito agregarle la variable para obtener `imgDG#` donde # sea el número de la tupla que se este leyendo.*

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres ver el índice en el array a los que pertenecen ciertos valores ejecuta :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) {
            echo nl2br ($row['column_name']."\n"); 
            echo print_r($row);
```

Esto te `devolverá los índices, las columnas y su valores`. De esta forma sabrás los valores que perteneces a cada índice del array.

A partir de aquí ya decides que función le quieres dar a los valores/variables dentro de tu función.

***SENTENCIA DE EJEMPLO :***

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) {
            if ($row[0]==52) {
                $email = $row[1];
            }
            echo nl2br ($row['column_name']. PHP_EOL);
            echo print_r($row);  
        }
```

Donde tenemos en cuenta que `row[0]` pertenece a las ID's y `row[1]` a los email.

***OTRO EJEMPLO :***

```
function consultaDb($tabla,$id) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tabla";
        $result = $GLOBALS['mysql']->query($query);
        $email = "";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($row[0]==$id) {
                $email = $row[1];
            }
            echo nl2br ($row['column_name']. PHP_EOL);
            echo print_r($row);  
        }  
    }
```

Añadiendo el parámetro`$id` a la función anterior, guardamos en la variable `email` el valor encontrado si los id's coinciden.

Comment: Cualquier duda o aclaración escribe un mensaje.

Comment: @SantiagoBarreiro porque estas utilizando `fetch_assoc` en vez de `fetch_array`

Comment: Ok, @Alexci lo que no me queda claro es por decir utilizando print_r() en donde me indica por pantalla el índice de cada elemento, como almaceno ese número de índice en una variable o una función que detecte en que fila se encuentra y que haya la posibilidad de agregarla en la parte final del identificador.

Comment: En `OTRO EJEMPLO` tienes allí como almacenar un valor en concreto dentro de una variable (`email`). Si en vez de querer guardar un solo elemento quieres guardarlo todo crea un array donde por cada row hagas un `push` al array, así obtendrás todos los valores ;D